# How to parser and serialise the markdown code in nodejs, using @milkdown/preset-gfm

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown, prose-mirror

I am using yjs and milkdown for building a collaborative markdown editor and I want to store the documents on disk in markdown only not in a database as yjs-websocket does. I was able to do it with common mark, but that is limited in syntax.

My final goal is to have something like this

```js
import remarkGFM from 'remark-gfm';
import { ParserState, SerializerState } from '@milkdown/transformer';
import { schema, gfm } from '@milkdown/preset-gfm';
import * as Y from 'yjs';
import { prosemirrorToYDoc, yDocToProsemirror } from 'y-prosemirror';
import { Schema } from '@milkdown/prose/model';

/** Build Schema?? */
const S = new Schema({
 nodes: {},
 marks: {}
});

const remark = remarkGFM() as import('unified').Transformer<
 import('mdast').Root,
 import('mdast').Root
>;
/** Build a processor?? */
const parser = ParserState.create(S, remark);
const serializer = SerializerState.create(schema, remark);

export function CommonMarkToString(doc: Y.Doc) {
 const str = serializer(yDocToProsemirror(schema, doc));
 return str;
}

export function CommonMarkToDoc(value: string) {
 return prosemirrorToYDoc(parser(value));
}
```

But obviously, the above code is wrong. I don't know if I am doing it the right way.